# How to replace a ExpressionSyntax by an ArgumentSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'd like to know what are my options?
I have a situation where this code :

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Changed;

FooBase()
{
    Changed += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(HandleChanged);
}

void HandleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

must be fixed and changed into the following code :

```
   public class FooBase
   {
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Changed;

    FooBase()
    {
        Changed += HandleChanged;
    }

    void HandleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
   }
```

This is a situation where the creation of a delegate has become redundant. I'm facing an ObjectCreationExpression and I need to replace it with it's argument (ArgumentSyntax).

In the following code, I have bout everything, except what I'm about to say. An assignmentexpression is composed by it's left and right parts. Both of those are expression syntax. What bugs me at the moment is that I need to create an expression syntax out of an argument syntax which can't happen at the moment for me and I'm look for a way for how to do it !

Code fix :

```
        public async override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
    {
        var document = context.Document;
        var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;
        var span = context.Span;
        var diagnostics = context.Diagnostics;
        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
        var diagnostic = diagnostics.First();
        var assignmentExpression = root.FindNode(context.Span) as AssignmentExpressionSyntax;
        var objectCreation = assignmentExpression?.Right as ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax;
        var argument = objectCreation?.ArgumentList.Arguments[0];

        if (argument == null)
            return;

        var argumentAsExpressionStatement = SyntaxFactory.AssignmentExpression(assignmentExpression.Kind(),
            assignmentExpression.Left, argument); //Does not compile
        var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(objectCreation, 
            argument
            .WithoutLeadingTrivia()
            .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation));
        context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeActionFactory.Create(assignmentExpression.Span, diagnostic.Severity, "Remove redundant 'new'", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)), diagnostic);
    }
```

For those who might wonder how I can figure out when a delegate's creation is redundant, here's the code analysis that I used :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;

namespace RefactoringEssentials.CSharp.Diagnostics
{
    [DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class RedundantDelegateCreationAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
    {
        private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor descriptor = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
            CSharpDiagnosticIDs.RedundantDelegateCreationAnalyzerID,
            GettextCatalog.GetString("Explicit delegate creation expression is redundant"),
            GettextCatalog.GetString("Redundant explicit delegate declaration"),
            DiagnosticAnalyzerCategories.RedundanciesInCode,
            DiagnosticSeverity.Warning,
            isEnabledByDefault: true,
            helpLinkUri: HelpLink.CreateFor(CSharpDiagnosticIDs.RedundantDelegateCreationAnalyzerID),
            customTags: DiagnosticCustomTags.Unnecessary
        );

        public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(descriptor);

        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
        {
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
                (nodeContext) =>
                {
                    Diagnostic diagnostic;
                    if (TryGetDiagnostic(nodeContext, out diagnostic))
                    {
                        nodeContext.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                    }
                },
                 SyntaxKind.ExpressionStatement
            );
        }

        private static bool TryGetDiagnostic(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext nodeContext, out Diagnostic diagnostic)
        {
            diagnostic = default(Diagnostic);
            if (nodeContext.IsFromGeneratedCode())
                return false;


            var semanticModel = nodeContext.SemanticModel;
            var expressionStatement = nodeContext.Node as ExpressionStatementSyntax;
            var addOrSubstractExpression = expressionStatement?.Expression as AssignmentExpressionSyntax;
            var rightMember = addOrSubstractExpression?.Right as ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax;

            if (rightMember == null || rightMember.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count != 1)
                return false; 

            var leftTypeInfo = ModelExtensions.GetTypeInfo(semanticModel, addOrSubstractExpression.Left).ConvertedType;
            if (leftTypeInfo == null || leftTypeInfo.Kind.Equals(SyntaxKind.EventDeclaration))
                return false;

            diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(descriptor, addOrSubstractExpression.Right.GetLocation());
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnKoerner, what would you suggest me to do here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that inside the ArgumentSyntax class, there's a property of the type ExpressionSyntax which old the reference to the method which will be referenced by the delegate.

So, the code becomes this ! :

```
        var assignmentExpression = root.FindNode(context.Span) as AssignmentExpressionSyntax;
        var objectCreation = assignmentExpression?.Right as ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax;
        var argument = objectCreation?.ArgumentList.Arguments[0];

        if (argument == null)
            return;

        var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(objectCreation, 
            argument.Expression
            .WithoutLeadingTrivia()
            .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation));
        context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeActionFactory.Create(assignmentExpression.Span, diagnostic.Severity, "Remove redundant 'new'", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)), diagnostic);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question well, you just need to replace ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax with IdentifierNameSyntax (HandleChanged) not with ArgumentSyntax.
Here is the edited code

```
public async override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
{
    var document = context.Document;
    var cancellationToken = context.CancellationToken;
    var span = context.Span;
    var diagnostics = context.Diagnostics;
    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    var diagnostic = diagnostics.First();
    var assignmentExpression = root.FindNode(context.Span) as AssignmentExpressionSyntax;
    var objectCreation = assignmentExpression?.Right as ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax;
    var argument = objectCreation?.ArgumentList.Arguments[0];

    if (argument == null)
        return;

   var identifier = argument.DescendantNodes()
                    .OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>).First();
   var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(objectCreation,
           SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(identifier.Identifier.Text)); 


context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeActionFactory.Create(assignmentExpression.Span, diagnostic.Severity, "Remove redundant 'new'", document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot)), diagnostic);
}
```

Comment: It remains the same thing, syntaxnode cannot take the place of a expressionsyntaxnode

Comment: Do you have any more insight on this situation?

Comment: `var identifier = argument.DescendantNodes()
                       .OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();

            
if (null != identifier){
                  var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(objectCreation, SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(identifier.Identifier.Text));
//continue
}`

Comment: I think you don't need this
var argumentAsExpressionStatement = SyntaxFactory.AssignmentExpression(assignmentExpression.Kind(),
            assignmentExpression.Left, argument);

Comment: The tests don't run, sorry :/

Comment: What does it say, whats the problem

Comment: There no fix for REC00164
Which means that something was a null reference in the code fix provider. 
I found exactly what I needed. 
I understand what you tried to do for me, it's really nice. The thing is with that answer is that you're using ChildNodes. Code fixes need to be as fast as they can possibly be. Using ChildNodes cost a lot performance wise, so I would have tried to make sense of your answer if I hadn't find out the answer to this question.

Comment: Using properties is the best way to go when you're playing around with the Roslyn platform. But thank you for your help, it helped me figure it out !

Comment: Cheers, no problem :)